# Obtaining a feasible solution for underdetermined system of linear equations satisfying inequality constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, constrained-optimization, nonlinear-programming, least-squares

I would like to obtain a feasible solution for an **under-determined** system of linear equations,

$$Ax=b$$

where,  $A \in \mathbb{R}^{7\times9}, \, x \in \mathbb{R}^{9\times1}\text{and } b\in\mathbb{R}^{7\times1}$.

Clearly, there is no unique solution, but I would like to obtain a solution that satisfies some **non-linear inequality** conditions for a few components in $x$,

\begin{align}
f_1(x_1,x_2,x_3) &\le c_1 \\
f_2(x_7,x_8,x_9) &\le c_2 \\
\end{align}

To be specific, the inequalities are $|x_1 + x_2 + x_3 - k| \le c_1$ and $|x_7 + x_8 + x_9 - k| \le c_2$ , i.e. the only non-linearity here is the `abs()` function.

I am happy with any solution $x^*$ that satisfies the underdetermined system exactly whilst also satisfying the two constraints above.

I am currently using MATLAB as my programming environment, but pseudo-code/links to useful resources etc shall be more than enough to get started. An example MATLAB code for a dummy problem shall also be very helpful.

Comment: Apply `fmincon` to the normal equations?

Comment: @Rahul, I doubt that is even possible. fmincon minimizes only a scalar function, see here https://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html .

Comment: Well, I think you have answered your own question. $g(x) = \|Ax-b\|_2$ is a scalar function, and `fmincon` can certainly handle problems of the form $\min_x g(x) \;\; s.t \;\; f_1(x)\le c_1, \;\; f_2(x) \le c_2$.

Comment: "Nonlinear" is too broad. Quadratic? Polynomial? And if the system is underdetermined, why use least-squares? Why not least-norm?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes. My inequality constraints are mostly linear, i.e. they are of the form $|x_1 + x_2 + x_3 - k| \le c_1$, where $k$ and $c_1$ are just scalar numerical values. The non-linearity comes solely due to absolute value function. Is there a way of converting this to a 'quadratic' or other well-posed linear problem? I too feel that using a general NLP solver like ```fmincon``` is like using a sledgehammer rather than a scalpel.

Comment: Why not write $-c_1 \leq x_1 + x_2 + x_3 - k \leq c_1$? It is the conjunction of two linear inequalities. Also, you don't have an objective function. There is nothing to minimize. You have linear equality and inequality constraints. Deciding whether there exists a feasible solution can be done via linear programming.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thank you. That indeed makes sense. So first I convert the inequalities to be $\le$ and then apply ```linprog```  https://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html from the optimization toolbox? ```x = linprog(f,A,b,Aeq,beq) ``` wherein ```f = 0``` ,right?

Comment: Correct if `0` denotes a zero vector.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thank you. That does indeed work!  Just tried it. The solution is unique because it is a linear programming problem. If you write your final comments as an answer, I can accept it for the benefit of whoever lands here in the future through a google search. Yes, ```0``` $\in \mathbb{R}^{9\times1}$ here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73795/discussion-between-krishna-and-rodrigo-de-azevedo).

Comment: You can save yourself the "pain" and error propensity of figuring out how to use quadprog by using CVX. cvx_begin;variable x(9);minimize(norm(x));A*x == b;abs(sum(x(1:3) - k) <= c1;abs(sum(x(7:9) - k) <= c2;cvx_end  At the conclusion of which x will contain its optimal value and be available in MATLAB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was already solved in the comments section using linprog. Also CVX...

I wanted just to point out that `fmincon` can also be used: just set the linear equality constraints `Ax=b` and construct a nonlinear constraint function after the model `[c,ceq,G,Geq] = nonlcon(x)`, where the constraints will be of the form `c <= 0`, `ceq =0` and `G` and `Geq` are the respective gradients. This works for more general non-linear functions $f_1,f_2$ than the ones mentioned in the question. For the objective function just put a fictious one, like `@(x) 0`